# Get name of an HTML element with PHP parsing

Tags: php, html, parsing

so say I have an HTML page like this.

```
<input type="text" name="name" />
<input type="hidden" name="test" value="test_result1" />
<input type="hidden" name="test2" value="test_result2" />
```

I want to parse that HTML page (from a url, using file_get_contents?), then get the names of the input elements that have the type "hidden".

Basically what I want parsed from that page is

```
test
test2
```

Is there a way to do this? I looked into some parsing libraries (like SimpleHTMLDom), but I just couldn't do it.

Comment: You looked in the right place, you just have to learn how to use it.

Comment: @JayBlanchard Shouldn't it be something like this? `$html->find('input[type=hidden]');`

Comment: @JayBlanchard When I do that I get the full line, not the name of it, can you please tell me where to look?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using the SimpleHTMLDom

```
$html = file_get_html('http://www.google.com/');

// Find all inputs
foreach($html->find('input') as $element){ 
    $type = $element->type;
    if($type=='hidden'){
        echo $element->name. '<br/>';
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use php DOMDocument.

```
$html = "<html>
        <body>
            <form>
                <input type='text' name='not_in_results'/>
                <input type='hidden' name='test1'/>
                <input type='hidden' name='test2'/>
            </body>
        </html>";

$dom = new DOMDocument;
$dom->loadHTML($html);
$inputs = $dom->getElementsByTagName('input');

$hiddenInputNames = [];

foreach ($inputs as $input) {
    if($input->getAttribute('type') == "hidden")
        $hiddenInputNames[] = $input->getAttribute('name');
}

var_dump($hiddenInputNames);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
include 'simple_html_dom.php';
$data = file_get_html('index.html');
$nodes = $data->find("input[type=hidden]");
foreach ($nodes as $node) {
  $val = $node->name;
  echo $val . "<br />";
}
```

Output:

```
test
test2
```

In this case, you have to include  [php simple html dom par](https://sourceforge.net/projects/simplehtmldom/files/)

Answer (score 0):

simple_html_dom is easy to use, but also very old and not very fast. Using php's DOMDocument is much faster, but also not as easy as simple_html_dom. An alternative would be something like [DomQuery](https://github.com/Rct567/DomQuery), which basically give you jquery like access to php's DOMDocument. It would be as simple as:

```
$dom = new DomQuery(file_get_html('index.html'))
foreach($dom->find('input[type=hidden]') as $elm) {
    echo $elm->name; 
}
```

Comment: This question has an accepted answer from several months ago, not sure how much value this adds to the discussion.